# Msvm_ImageManagementService invalid namespace

Tags: wmi

Running the following powershell command I get invalid namespace, on windows 7 (on a vm, more or less a fresh install). It just imports the class and doesn't do anything else. Any reason why?

```
get-wmiobject -class "Msvm_ImageManagementService" -namespace "root/virtualization" -computername "."
```

Comment: I am also getting this.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. I am developing my powershell on a windows 7 machine, but the target is Windows 2008R2. There is no support for Hyper-V services in Win7.

See:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a08ad18f-4b6a-46a0-bd1f-274fbbc5b737/attach-a-vhd-in-windows-7